# openapi-generator spring boot: combining json and text response

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using the openapi-generator to create a spring-boot server. I am currently still in the experimentation phase.

The goal is that the server is able to provide multiple response media-types, depending on the media type that is accepted by the requester. According to different sources, this should be possible. See [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/#media-types) for example of how the yaml file would then look. Other similar examples can be found here on stack overflow.

Concrete example. Let's say we have a post request where if a name is posted the name is returned (just a silly example). In case the requester sends the name John Doe and does not accept application/json, the response, in plain text, should look like this:

```
John Doe
```

In case the requester accepts application/json the response should look like this:

```
{"name": "John Doe"}
```

For explaining my question/problem I created an example spring boot server. At one point it has the path /user for which the response is:

```
      responses:
          '200':
            description: The username.
            content: 
              application/json:
                schema:
                  properties:
                    name:
                      type: string
                      example: John Doe 
              text/plain:
                schema:
                  type: string
                  example: John Doe
```

On the other hand I created the path /getuser (name is not really fortunate but it is for this example) which returns the following response:

```
          '200':
            description: The username.
            content: 
              text/plain:
                schema:
                  type: string
                  example: John Doe  
              application/json:
                schema:
                  properties:
                    name:
                      type: string
                      example: John Doe
```

My problem is the following: for the first example, where I put the application/json first in the yaml file, the API looks like this:

```
    default ResponseEntity<UserPost200Response> userPost(
        @Parameter(name = "name", description = "The name of the user.") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
        @Parameter(name = "UserPostRequest", description = "") @Valid @RequestBody(required = false) UserPostRequest userPostRequest
    ) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    String exampleString = "{ \"name\" : \"John Doe\" }";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

If, however, I would like to return a `ResponseEntity<String>` this gives an error since UserPost200Response is not used.

For the path /getuser, where the String response is first defined in the yaml file, my API looks like this:

```
    default ResponseEntity<String> getuserPost(
        @Parameter(name = "name", description = "The name of the user.") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
        @Parameter(name = "UserPostRequest", description = "") @Valid @RequestBody(required = false) UserPostRequest userPostRequest
    ) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    String exampleString = "\"John Doe\"";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

This API makes it possible to return a `ResponseEntity<String>` but not a `ResponseEntity<UserPost200Response>` which defines the above mentioned json-model.

One workaround that I found, would be to use the path where the string-response is declared first in the yaml file (see /getuser) in the example above and that returns a `ResponseEntity<String>` and override and do something like this:

```
    default ResponseEntity<String> getuserPost(
        @Parameter(name = "name", description = "The name of the user.") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
        @Parameter(name = "UserPostRequest", description = "") @Valid @RequestBody(required = false) UserPostRequest userPostRequest
    ) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    String exampleString = "{ \"name\" : \"John Doe\" }";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("text/plain"))) {
                    String exampleString = "John Doe";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "text/plain", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
            }
       });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

In this case, I don't use the Model created by the openapi-generator and treat the JSON basically as a string.

Another option is to go for a wildcard like ResponseEntity<?> but from what I understand, except proven the contrary, this seems bad practice. I haven't figured out how to declare this in the .yml file that is used by the openapi-generator.

Neither options seem to respect the contract.

I wonder if (1) I am doing something wrong here and (2) how it could be better implemented. The goal is of course to not rewrite the API's and only implement the logic in the Controllers. Any ResponseEntity in the API's should thus not be changed.